# Downloading Pokemon Go

Tags: applications, pokemon-go

My name is Joseph, and I live in Vancouver, BC, Canada. 
I own a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 Lite, and I'm trying to download Pokemon GO.
All my friends have it, but I cannot find it on my device.
I updated everything and checked daily, but it would never show up.
Please tell me why I cannot download Pokemon GO, and if possible, when I can download it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The primary reason it isn't showing up is because you are on Android JellyBean (4.1/4.2/4.3) and not KitKat (4.4) or higher which is required for Pokemon Go, according to Google there never was an official update to KitKat on the SG Tab3 Lite... This is the core requirement, the rest of the issues should not stop you from downloading and installing, although they could cause the game to not function correctly.

Answer (score 2):

From the Pokémon Go entry in the Google Play Store:

```
- This app is free-to-play and offers in-game purchases.
  It is optimized for smartphones, not tablets.
```

Your device is a tablet

```
- Compatible with Android devices that have 2GB RAM or
  more and have Android Version 4.4 - 6.0 installed.
```

Your device isn't running KitKat (4.4) and only has 1 GB of RAM

```
- Compatibility is not guaranteed for devices without GPS
  capabilities or devices that are connected only to Wi-Fi networks
```

Your device only has Wi-Fi so unless the Poké-stops are around Wi-Fi hotspots your collection is limited.

```
- Compatibility with tablet devices is not guaranteed.
```

Your device is a tablet.

**Answer**: Save up your allowance or get a summer job to buy a device which is supported by *Pokémon Go*, and if your allowed to a cellphone data plan.